# What is the id of the listener container when using Spring's JMS namespace?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-jms

According to the [Spring Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/jms.html#jms-namespace) for the JMS Namespace tags (i.e. `<jms:listener-container>`), there  is no `id` attribute for a `<jms:listener-container>` element.

How do I reference the listener container bean from other bean definitions if there is no `id` for it?

For example, say I have the following Listener container defined:

```
<jms:listener-container acknowledge="auto"
    connection-factory="queueConnectionFactoryBean"
    container-type="default"
    destination-resolver="jndiDestinationResolver"
    destination-type="queue"
    message-converter="myConverter">

    <jms:listener ref="myListenerPOJO" id="myQueueListener"
        method="processThePOJO" destination="${myQueueListener.queue.jndiName}" />

</jms:listener-container>
```

And I want to define an inbound gateway that uses the above container. What would I use as the `container` property for the inbound gateway definition?

Example:

```
<int-jms:inbound-gateway 
    request-channel="inboundChannel"
    id="messageChannelAdapter"
    container="**What Goes Here?**"
    reply-channel="outboundChannel" />
```

Or am I misunderstanding the relationship between listener container and gateway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `listener-container` element isn't meant for configuring a standalone JMS listener container. It is meant to act as a blueprint for all enclosed `listener` tags. What, at runtime, actually happens is that a JMS Listener Container is constructed for each enclosed `listener`. So there is not a single container but multiple.

As @artembilan mentioned the id of the container is set to the id of the listener. However when you would reuse the listener for spring integration it would render the listener useless. A listener-container can only have a single MessageListener attached, not multiple.

If you want to use a listener container for a Spring Integration gateway you will have to construct one yourself using one of the `*MessageListenerContainer` classes.

Comment: Thank you that clears it up. I think if you can add in the bit from @Artem Bilan about how the id of the container = the id of the listener I can mark as answer.

Answer (score 3):

As Marten said, `listener-container` pupolates the `MessageListenerContainer` beans for each `listener` sub-element. And what is magic the target `MessageListenerContainer` gets the `id` from the listener's `id`.

So, in your case the `<int-jms:inbound-gateway>`'s `container` should apply the value **myQueueListener**.

Comment: Although you could try that, that would disable the listener (at least it should). A MessageListenerContainer can only serve a single listener, not multiple.

Comment: Here is a source code how it heppens: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-jms/src/main/java/org/springframework/jms/config/AbstractListenerContainerParser.java#L104